# General centralizer of algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Perhaps there is a simple answer, but I'm very puzzled by the following question:

**Question**: Does there exist a (smooth, connected) algebraic group $G$ such that the general centralizer (i.e. the centralizer in a Zariski open set) is finite?

I'm pretty sure the answer is no (maybe some extra assumptions such as reductive, algebraically closed field... must be added), but I have no clue about how to prove it.

Of course, typical groups such as $GL_n, SL_n, O_n...$ are not counterexamples.

Thank you!

Comment: In a connected algebraic group of positive dimension, there is no element at all with finite centralizer. Indeed such an element would have an open conjugacy class, and this is not possible.

Comment: #YCor could you please give some references for these statements?

Comment: I mean, I obviously understand why such element has an open conjugacy class, but I don't see why is that a problem.

Comment: Passing to a quotient, we can suppose $G$ simple or abelian, and the abelian case is trivial to discard, so we can suppose $G$ simple. Then the condition would also mean that a generic element has finite order. Say, over the complex numbers, this implies that there exists $n$ such that $g^n=1$ for all $g$. But a simple algebraic group contains up to isogeny a copy of $\mathrm{SL}_2$.

Comment: @YCor Your argument works over fields of arbitrary characteristic. One can finish over the complex numbers by noting that $g^n=1$ is a contradiction for $g$ in a small neighborhood of $1$, but this doesn't work in characteristic $p$. However, your argument with splitting into cases and using $SL_2$ does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every element $g\in G$ is contained in a Borel subgroup $B\subseteq G$. The quotient $B^{ab}:=B/(B,B)$ has positive dimension since $B$ is solvable. Moreover, the $B$-conjugacy class of $g$ maps to a point in $B^{ab}$. Hence $\dim B/C_B(g)\le\dim (B,B)$ and therefore $\dim C_G(g)\ge\dim C_B(g)\ge \dim B^{ab}>0$.